# Problem animating polar plots from measured data

Tags: python, dataframe, visualization, plotly-python, polar-coordinates

**Problem**

I'm trying to animate a polar plot from a measured temperature data from a cylinder using the plotly.express command line_polar by using a dataset of 6 radial values (represented by columns #1 - #6) over 10 rows (represented by column Time) distributed over a polar plot. I'm struggling to make it animate and get the following error:

**Error**

> ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of column argument `df[animation_frame]` is 10, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['r', 'theta'] is 6

According to the help for the parameter "animation_frame" it should be specified as following:

> animation_frame (str or int or Series or array-like) – Either a name of a column in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from this column or array_like are used to assign marks to animation frames.

I'm a bit stumped with this problem since I don't see why this shouldn't work, since other use cases seem to use multi-dimensional data with the data with equal rows.

**Example of polar plot for t=1**

[Polar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC34C.png)

**Dataset:**

| Time | #1 | #2 | #3 | #4 | #5 | #6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 175 | 176 | 179 | 182 | 178 | 173 |
| 2 | 174 | 175 | 179 | 184 | 178 | 172 |
| 3 | 175 | 176 | 178 | 183 | 179 | 174 |
| 4 | 173 | 174 | 178 | 184 | 179 | 174 |
| 5 | 173 | 174 | 177 | 185 | 180 | 175 |
| 6 | 173 | 174 | 177 | 185 | 180 | 175 |
| 7 | 172 | 173 | 176 | 186 | 181 | 176 |
| 8 | 172 | 173 | 176 | 186 | 181 | 176 |
| 9 | 171 | 172 | 175 | 187 | 182 | 177 |
| 10 | 171 | 172 | 175 | 187 | 182 | 177 |

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_excel('TempData.xlsx')

sensor = ["0", "60", "120", "180", "240","300"]
radial_all = ['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', '#6']

fig = px.line_polar(df, r=radial_all, theta=sensor, line_close=True,
                     color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r, template="plotly_dark", animation_frame="Time")
fig.update_polars(radialaxis_range=[160, 190])
fig.update_polars(radialaxis_rangemode="normal")
fig.update_polars(radialaxis=dict(tickvals = [150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem, its also possible with scatterpolar but I recommend line_polar from plotly express, its way more elegant and easy. What you need to do is format the data from wide to long format using the pandas command melt(). This will allow you to correctly walk through the data and match it to the animation steps (in this case "Time" column). See following links for helpful info.

[Pandas - reshaping-by-melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt)

[pandas.melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Resulting code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.read_excel('TempData.xlsx')

df_1 = df.melt(id_vars=['Time'], var_name="Sensor", value_name="Temperature",
               value_vars=['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4','#5','#6'])
    
fig = px.line_polar(df_1, r="Temperature", theta="Sensor", line_close=True,
                    line_shape="linear", direction="clockwise",
                   color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma_r, template="plotly_dark",
                    animation_frame="Time")
  
fig.show()
```

[Resulting animating plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa1Vo.png)